# Show that $\int_{\tau}^{\infty}\frac{\exp(u)}{[1+\exp(u)]^2}du=\frac{\exp(-\tau)}{1+\exp(-\tau)}$

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

How $$\int_{\tau}^{\infty}\frac{\exp(u)}{[1+\exp(u)]^2}du=\frac{\exp(-\tau)}{1+\exp(-\tau)}$$?

#### My Attempt :

let $z=1+\exp(u)$

$\frac{dz}{du}=\exp(u)$

$$
\begin{array}{c|c|c|}
u&\tau&\infty\\
\hline
z&1+\exp(\tau)&\infty
\end{array}
$$

So,

$$\int_{\tau}^{\infty}\frac{\exp(u)}{[1+\exp(u)]^2}du$$

$$=\int_{1+\exp(\tau)}^{\infty}\frac{dz}{z^2}$$

$$=[\frac{-1}{z}]_{1+\exp(\tau)}^{\infty}$$

$$=\frac{1}{1+\exp(\tau)}.$$

But I have to show $\int_{\tau}^{\infty}\frac{\exp(u)}{[1+\exp(u)]^2}du=\frac{\exp(-\tau)}{1+\exp(-\tau)}$. How can I do that ?

Comment: let $x=1+e^u$ and proceed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$
\int_{\tau}^{\infty}\tfrac{\exp(u)}{[1+\exp(u)]^2}du=\left.-\tfrac{1}{1+\exp(u)}\right|_\tau^\infty=\frac{1}{1+\exp(\tau)}=\tfrac{\exp(-\tau)}{\exp(-\tau)}\cdot\frac{1}{1+\exp(\tau)}=\frac{\exp(-\tau)}{1+\exp(-\tau)}
$$